# Am I reasonably safe in assuming file will open?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have a program where I need to take in a command line argument that is the name of a text file. The program is run by ./programName file1. If for the purpose of my program I can assume file1 will always be formatted correctly, can I just do

```
ifstream myFile(argv[1]);
    if(!myFile.good()){
        cout << "Not a valid player file" << endl;
        return 1;   
    }
```

to check if there is such a file, and then simply

```
myFile >> var1;
myFile >> var2;
myFile.close();
```

or should I stick with

```
if(myFile.is_open()){
        myFile >> var1;
        myFile >> var2;
        myFile.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
```

Again I can assume the file will always be formatted correctly(i.e myFile >> var# will always work). So is there any situation in which the `else` statement might be called after my initial check of `(!myFile.good())`?

Comment: for `good()` to return true, `is_open()` must also be true.  That is, you can go with `good()` (or, my favorite, change to `if (myFile) ...`, which means the same thing).

Comment: so just to check, in my case since I'm checking !good() I could do if(!myFile)?

Comment: Correct, and common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should mainly check the input operations, to know if your file has the proper input format:

```
if(myFile >> var1 >> var2) {
    // Everything's fine
}
else {
   // WRONG FORMAT OR COULDN'T BE OPENED!
}
```

To know the actual error reason in the `else` part, you can inspect the [`iostate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) flags returned by the [`std::istream::rdstate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate) function.

If the `open()` failed the `badbit` will be set, if one of the input operations failed the `failbit` will be set.

Comment: They should check if a file was actually opened too. E.g. for the time of opening the application might not have a rights to access a file — a pretty often problem in a wild.